# creating a folder in yahoo's inbox

Tags: oauth, yahoo, yql

after `OAuth` process I just want to create folders in yahoo and move some emails to it,
is it possible to do it using `YQL` if no is there another way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are SOAP/JSON calls to [Create a Folder](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/CreateFolder.html) as well as for [Moving Messages](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/MoveMessages.html) for Yahoo Mail.